# HangFire delayed tasks with date

Tags: date, task, hangfire

How can I add date to the HangFire task?
For example, this code adds 7 days:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Reliable!"), 
    TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

But what if I need to run task in specific date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the year doesn't matter, you can use cron expression for this purpose. Most default cron implementations (like [NCrontab](https://code.google.com/p/ncrontab/) used by Hangfire) don't include the year field.

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Reliable!"), 
    "30 4 27 6 *");
```

This job will be executed at 4.30am on the 27th of June every year.

Comment: I am also using BackgroundJob.Schedule to schedule a job, as per my knowledge it should queue a job only once at specified time. But I observe some time multiple job entries are queued for same delayed job with very less time difference. any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

As the developer answerd my question [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html#comment-2174202671), You can simply use the date instead of day(s).

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Reliable!"), 
    new DateTime(2015, 08, 05, 12, 00, 00));
```

For 05/08/2015 at 00:00.

[Jerry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29846859/5198896) answer is true for RecurringJobs

```
RecurringJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Reliable!"), 
    "00 00 05 8 *");
```

which will run every year on 05/08 at 00:00

Comment: Currently there's no `Schedule` method in `RecurringJob` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cron.Yearly()` to run it once a year at certain date-time:

```cs
// Will run on 4th of July @ 8 AM UTC every year
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Happy 4th of July!"), 
    Cron.Yearly(7, 4, 8, 0));
```